# JobDSL triggers deprecated, pipelineTriggers closure problem

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm using jobdsl 1.76 and trying to migrate to 1.77: from triggers to pipelineTriggers:

```
    pipelineJob('testPipelineTriggers'){
    
    properties {
            pipelineTriggers {
                triggers {
                   cron{
                       spec("* * * * *")
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This simple code giving me below error which I couldnt understand:

```
No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.properties.PropertiesContext.pipelineTriggers() is applicable for argument types: (XXX$__clinit__closure1$_closure2$_closure7$_closure9) values: [XXX$__clinit__closure1$_closure2$_closure7$_closure9@3c818ac4]
```

note: I replaced our groovy filename with 'XXX'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you managed to solve your problem, but I am using [Job DSL plugin 1.87](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/) and this is my script:

```
pipelineJob("MY/JOB/WORKSPACE/TMP") {
    description("my description")
    keepDependencies(false)
    properties {
        pipelineTriggers {
            triggers {
                cron {
                    spec('40 2 * * 1-5')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it works fine.